# Task does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'

Tags: c#, async-await

> Error CS1061  'Task>' does not contain a definition for
>   'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'Task>' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ,

making a web application with facebook controller, included using system.linq but still getting the error for `FirstOrDefault()`.
I dont know what the problem is, i reinstalled visual studio too as he same thing works for my friends laptop.
I juggled around to see if the method is present in the library and it is there but still not getting past this [Image for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9s7p.jpg)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Posts()
{
    var currentClaims = UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(HttpContext.Identity.GetUserId());

    // Error occurs here at FirstOrDefault
    var accesstoken = currentClaims.FirstOrDefault(x = > x.Type == "urn:tokens:facebook");

    if (accesstoken == null)
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the currentClaims variable ? To use FirstOrDefault the type must be IEnumerable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing an `await` in front of `UserManager.GetClaimsAsync()`:

```
var currentClaims = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look closely at the error message. `GetClaimsAsync` returns type `Task<IList<Claim>>`, *not* type list. The `Task` type doesn't have a `FirstOrDefault` method. As other people have indicated, await `GetClaimsAsync` and it'll work.

As a side note, do *not* use `.Result` here as that will deadlock in most environments. See [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for an explanation of why this will deadlock as well as [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) on async/await best practices.